# WPF Get brush color from brush resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource, dynamicresource

I need get color from brush dynamically.
So, I have a brush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ExampleBrush" Color="Black" />
```

So, it possible get color (for another brush, for example):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AnotherBrush" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource ExampleBrush}, Path=Color}" />
```

So, my question is **how it possible to get this for dynamic resources?**
Just because if I change the resource file with `ExampleBrush` - color of `AnotherBrush` not changing...

Please feel free to ask any questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `Color` property of AnotherBrush to the `Color` of the ExampleBrush using a `DynamicResource`. The workaround would be to use the `DynamicResource` to reference the ExampleBrush directly and bypass AnotherBrush:

```
<TextBlock Text="..." Foreground="{DynamicResource AnotherBrush}" />
```

You don't really need AnotherBrush as the `Foreground` of the `TextBlock` will still change whenever the AnotherBrush change. The results will be the same.

You could "bind" to the AnotherBrush as well but then you will need to update this brush explicitly whenever the ExampleBrush is updated:

```
<TextBlock Text="..." Foreground="{DynamicResource AnotherBrush}" />
```

Comment: What doesn't work? If your code doesn't work then you need to post an example of what you are trying to do if you want someone to be able to help you out...of course it works to use a DynamicResource.

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.screencast.com/t/33M28GoAvlf (ExampleBrush just check that resources has been changed)
Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible *code* sample of your issue. If you replace the "AnotherResource" with another brush the TextBlock in my sample markup should be updated.

Comment: You can download test project from onedrive, is that good for you? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AofHl6mOBGLrhZ50aAQbNcbepaDYFA

Comment: You should read my answer again. Don't use AnotherBrush in the AnotherBrushBorderStyle because this won't work. Use ExampleBrush instead and get rid of AnotherBrush:     <Style x:Key="AnotherBrushBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ExampleBrush}" />
    </Style>

Comment: It's just for example. Really I need to get color for create DropShadowEffect with ExampleBrush's color.